# How to get network info in android

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-networking

I want to get network info in android. Here is the image from google chrome windows.

[image]

You can see it as reference, but I need to find a way to get this info pragmatically in android

Comment: Why don't you open up the chrome on your android phone in debug mode. May be that helps ?

Comment: you know not easy to do why you want to do that on android ?

Comment: @SherazAhmadKhilji i want to do it pragmatically

Comment: @alirezaamini i  really dont know its easy or not , i just want to see traffic. infect network trafic

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the traffic usage of your network you can try this :

```
TextView infoView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.traffic_info);
String info = "";

info += "Mobile Interface:\n";
info += ("\tReceived: " + TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() + " bytes / " + TrafficStats.getMobileRxPackets() + " packets\n");
info += ("\tTransmitted: " + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes() + " bytes / " + TrafficStats.getMobileTxPackets() + " packets\n");

info += "All Network Interface:\n";
info += ("\tReceived: " + TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() + " bytes / " + TrafficStats.getTotalRxPackets() + " packets\n");
info += ("\tTransmitted: " + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() + " bytes / " +  TrafficStats.getTotalTxPackets() + " packets\n");

infoView.setText(info);
```

Comment: i want to get links info . i mean which api or link is calling in back-end . make sense ?

Comment: @SabaMehmood i dont know how to do that but this is all I KNOW :D